# How can I implement the lodash _.remove function in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this code using lodash:

```
    _.remove(this.home.modal.data.subTopics, function (currentObject) {
        return currentObject.subTopicId === subTopicToDelete;
    });
```

Can someone give me advice as to how I could do the same using modern browser functions without lodash?

Note it would be okay for the output of the remove to go into another variable.

Comment: You can see the source at https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L4060-L4075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter()` and negate the filter clause:

```
this.home.modal.data.subTopics.filter(function (currentObject) {
    return currentObject.subTopicId !== subTopicToDelete;
});
```

This will return an array where `subTopicId` does not equal `subTopicToDelete`. It's then up to you to save it in a variable or wherever.

---

Or, if you want to create a method out of it, you could do:

```
function remove(array, filterMethod) {
    return array.filter(function(){
        return !filterMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that this gets the correct set of results, but unlike `_.remove` it doesn't modify the original array. You need to assign the return value of `filter` to a `this.home.modal.data.subTopics`.

Comment: @lonesomeday - thanks for your feedback. I am okay if the original array is not modified.

Comment: @Scimonster - Thanks for your suggestions. Can you explain what you mean by Array#filter().  How could I use that for my needs if I intend the output to be into another variable.

Comment: @SamanthaJ `Array#filter` is the `filter` method on arrays. You pass in a callback, and for whatever items it returns `true`, it keeps in the array.

Comment: @Scimonster - If I wanted could I do this:         this.home.modal.data.subTopics = this.home.modal.data.subTopics.filter(function (currentObject) {
            return currentObject.subTopicId !== subTopicToDelete;
        });

Comment: Yes, you could, but now you have duplicated the array instead of modifying it in place, and only assigned the new array to the variable. What if you have some other part of your program pointing to the original array? That reference will never change. This is not really the behaviour of `_.remove`...

Answer (score 2):

Why not have a look at lodash's [source code for `_.remove`](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/2f79053d7bc7c9c9561a30dda202b3dcd2b72b90/remove.js)?

```
function remove(array, predicate, thisArg) {
  var index = -1,
      length = array ? array.length : 0,
      result = [];

  predicate = getCallback(predicate, thisArg, 3);
  while (++index < length) {
    var value = array[index];
    if (predicate(value, index, array)) {
      result.push(value);
      splice.call(array, index--, 1);
      length--;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

(The `getCallback` call is not really interesting here, just replace it with a predicate function that returns a boolean value for the given arguments: value, index, array. Not all of them need to be supplied obviously, this is JavaScript after all!)

Lodash uses [`Array.prototype.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) at the appropriate position, pushing the removed element onto the result array. Then it decreases the current loop index and the saved `length` by 1 using `--`, because every time you use `.splice`, you modify the array directly, for instance:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b'];
arr.splice(0, 1);
arr[1] // undefined
```

`splice` in this context really just the same as `Array.prototype.splice`. You can as well do `array.splice(index--, 1)`.

---

A maybe more simple/understandable way is to (for-)loop through the array from the right, starting at `array.length - 1` and ending at `0`. Then splice every element at the current index, if it passes the predicate function, and push the result value of that operation onto the result array. Return the result array after the loop.

This works the same, because if you start removing elements from the right side, the index of the rest of the looped elements doesn't change. Maybe there are performance advantages to lo-dash's code, but I couldn't tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt `Array.prototype` to suit your needs. Some people don't like this approach, but it can be useful sometimes. In this example I pass in the key and the value I want to amend the array by:

```
if (!Array.prototype.remove) {
  Array.prototype.remove = function (key, value) {
    return this.filter(function (el) {
       return el[key] !== value;
    });
  }
}

data.remove('name', 'dan');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dqpzgbmm/)